# Are there tutorials for how to transfer pictures with iTunes file sharing between Mac/PC and iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, file-sharing

I'd like some kind of overview tutorial that shows how this works. I have only found very specific ones so far which deal with complex problems like file packages etc., but I only need simple images import/export.

Does someone know a tutorial or example project which does just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never, I guess...

This is the best documentation I've seen for file sharing:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

If your needs are basic you can just enable UIFileSharingEnabled in your Info.plist and you should be able to read/write to the documents directory of the app without further coding.